# Console hangs on newline after getting user input

Tags: c#, user-input

I need this program to ask the user to input a number to add to an array. After they input the number, the console goes to a newline until you press another key, at which point it will do the same thing over again. I'm new to C# and I assume this has something to do with the fact that it's reading the enter key after the user inputs the information, so I need to use something equivalent to cin.ignore(), but I haven't been able to find anything that solves the issue.

```
public void InputSet()
{
    int userInput;

    do
    {
        C.Write("Enter an element (Enter to end): ");
        userInput = Convert.ToInt32(C.ReadLine()); // Read user input

        if (userInput < 1 || userInput > 50) // Check if in bounds
            C.WriteLine("Input is invalid. Enter from 1 to 50."); // Error message if out of bounds
        else
        {
            Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length + 1); // Expand array and then add it in
            arr[arr.Length - 1] = userInput;
        }
    } while(Console.ReadKey (true).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter); // If enter key is pressed, exit loop
```

Here is a video of the problem:
[Hanging on newline](https://i.gyazo.com/b014aa91560a88fe0f51b686d2a17d33.mp4)

Comment: Do you want to clear the Console or what, an empty line in the console or what do you exactly mean with `the console goes to a newline until you press another key`.

Comment: @Twenty I added a short video of the problem, but basically after the user inputs a number and presses enter, the console goes to a newline and just stays there until you push another key, at which point it prompts them to enter another number.

I want it to just keep asking for more numbers every time the user inputs a number and presses enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is not hanging - it is expecting an input in order to continue the while loop:

```
while(Console.ReadKey (true).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```

I have tested the code and it works fine - Perhaps you might want to feedback the user in what action to take in order to finish or to continue.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to terminate or C to continue");
    } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter); // If enter key is pressed, exit loop
```

Any key will do really.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure i understand your question or the problem

However,

1. You should probably be using a `List` instead of an *array*
2. You should be using `int.TryParse` to validate user input
3. You should probably be using `Console.ReadLine` instead of `ReadKey`
4. You can check `result == string.Empty` to exit

**Example**

```
var list = new List<int>();

while (true)
{
   Console.Write("Enter an element (Enter to end): ");
   var result = Console.ReadLine();

   if (result == string.Empty) break;
   if (!int.TryParse(result, out var value))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("You had one job...");
      continue;
   }
   list.Add(value);
} 

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", " , list));

Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

```
Enter an element (Enter to end): 2
Enter an element (Enter to end): 3
Enter an element (Enter to end): 4
Enter an element (Enter to end): 6
Enter an element (Enter to end): f
You had one job...
Enter an element (Enter to end):
2, 3, 4, 6
```

Comment: Professor's rubric instructs us to use arrays. I've been seeing that I should be using lists on all the threads I've looked at, though lol